# HSQLDB merge into can neither insert nor update

Tags: merge, hsqldb

I'm trying to use MERGE INTO to save or update HSQLDB table. I ran into an issue of inserting new record when NOT MATCHED.

Steps of reproduce the issue

1. Create table

`CREATE TABLE user (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(16),
  address VARCHAR(64)
);`

2. MERGE INTO

`MERGE INTO user u1
  USING (select id from user  where id=1) u2

    ON u1.id = u2.id

  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET u1.name='name', u1.address='address'

  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name, address) values(1, 'name', 'address')`

If there is no record with id:1, above statement doesn't nothing, "Updated Rows: 0".

If insert one record

`INSERT INTO user values(1, 'Y', 'B');`

above `MERGE INTO` statement can update the existing record.

Anyone knows what's the issue with INSERT WHEN NOT MATCHED? Is there the third case other than "WHEN MATCHED" and "WHEN NOT MATCHED"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this clause:

```
USING (select id from user  where id=1) u2
```

When there is no record in the table, there is no row generated by the USING clause. So there is nothing to insert or update the existing rows with.

You need to rewrite it so the USING clause generates a row with data.

For example:

```
USING (values(1)) u2(id)
```